# ECharts: align pie chart to the right

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am using a nested pie chart in my application -
The configuration is -

```
{
  options: {
    grid: {
        left: '300px'
    },
    legend: {
        orient: 'vertical',
        x: 'left',
        data: ['Autobots','Deceptiocons']
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Audit',
            type: 'pie',
            radius: [30%, '50%'],
            label: {
                normal: {
                    position: 'center',
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            },
            data: [{ value: 500, name: 'Autobots'},{ value: 500, name: 'Decepticons'}]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using grid , but still the chart is displayed in the center.

Answer (score 7):

Line chart, bar chart, and scatter chart (bubble chart) can be drawn in grid

For pie chart, please use Center position of Pie chart: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.center

```
center: ['20%', '50%']
```

Comment: Center helps you to set the hollow circle radius which is the first value i.e `20%` based on your example, then the second value sets the percentage size of the Chart depending on the available space. 100% would cover the whole area. Read more from official docs -> https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#title